# Find Users by Query inside a Active Directory Group

Tags: c#, active-directory, principalcontext

Given a particular group with a lot of members, I want to query within the group to find members that have a DisplayName match.

The code below is a non-functional example of what I'd like to accomplish. Note that I don't want to load the whole list first then apply the 'where', I can already do that and it is slow because the group is large.

```
    public static List<Principal> FindUsersOfGroup(string groupName, string displayNameQuery)
    {
        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, Environment.MachineName))
        {
            var search = new GroupPrincipal(context);
            search.SamAccountName = groupName;
            // This where doesn't work, but is what I'm looking for.
            search.Members.Where(m => m.DisplayName == displayNameQuery + "*");

            using (var ps = new PrincipalSearcher(search))
            {
                // Want to get all members that match the query AND belong to the group.
                return ps.FindAll().ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, the context is Domain in my real code, I replaced it on purpose.

Comment: Is it an option to use the [`DirectorySearcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class which is a different API than the one you are using?

Comment: Yes, using DirectorySearcher/DirectoryEntry is fine if it does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this with the [DirectorySearcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + Environment.UserDomainName))
{
    using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(
        entry,
        string.Format(
            "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(displayName={0}*)(memberof={1}))",
            displayNameQuery,
            groupName)))
    {

        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samAccountname"); //You can specify which properties you want to load. If you don't specify properties, by default you will get a lot of properties. Loading specific properties is better in terms of performance

        using (var results = searcher.FindAll())
        {
            foreach (var result in results.Cast<SearchResult>())
            {
                //Do something with result
                var properties = result.Properties;

                //Example
                var samAccountName = properties["samAccountName"][0];
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`groupName` in this case is the distinguished name of the group (e.g. CN=Administrators,CN=Builtin,DC=dnb,DC=lab)